# SharePoint Alert Email Messages and SPUser.RegionalSettings?

Tags: list, email, alert, timezone

All,

SharePoint 2010, I have setup an Alert on a Calendar (Events) list.  I have set to be notified on any change to the items in the list (add, edit, delete).  I have changed my user profile for the web using the /_layouts/regionalstngs.aspx?Type=user page to have a different time zone than that of the web site.  When I get my Alert emails, the Start/End date/time values are specified using as of the Time Zone for the user creating/editing the event, not the person to whom the alert email is delivered.

Is this a known limitation of SharePoint?  A bug in SharePoint?  Is there a workaround?

TIA!

Comment: I'd like to find the default/OOB Alert Handler to use Reflector to identify the code that is sending the alerts.  Anyone know where I can find this?  I have searched for "SPAlertHandlerParams" and "SPUtility.SendEmail(", but not finding any matches in the Microsoft.SharePoint assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is working as designed.

If you think about this in terms of an Airport - the departure times are always reported in the local time zone, not your own timezone, to do otherwise would lead to mass confusion.

Comment: The "believe" part is preventing me from marking as answer. I am looking to find the OOB (aka default) AlertHandler, but having no luck using Reflector to see if I can gain insight. Also, I am not buying the "airport" example. In an airport, you are physically present at arrival/departure. On a web site, it is at least 50% likely that you are virtual and as a result, only think in terms of your local time zone

Comment: You might not be able to find it in Reflector as believe it or not, the majority of SharePoints code is unmanaged and the .net object model is a wrapper for this. http://www.slideshare.net/kcponce/sharepoint-underground-unmanaged-code-and-sharepoint-internals

Answer (score 1):

I have the same problem for any user who has changed their time zone in their regional settings to something different than the server.  In my case, I set up a workflow to send a notification email for specific criteria in a list, however when the user that has a different time zone than the server creates the item, the date and time stamp in the email is the same as the user's local time.  Which is a problem for me because the users that receive the notifications are global.

The only workaround that I can think of in this case, is to have a drop down box in the form to ask the user what time zone they are in, which is stupid because the information is in the system.

It may be possible to create custom code for this, but not everyone has access to the master files or the server files to make such changes in SharePoint

Answer (score 0):

Alerts are stored in this table [ImmedSubscriptions]

What i have found is that alerts **ONLY** take the regional settings of the site.

Changing your user settings has no effect on the alerts store in the table, which kind of makes sense, because you dont have to send alerts to users only, you can send them to a security emailed mail groups.

You can also see if you change a site's regional settings, then all the alerts are updated to the new region, so it would not matter if user regional settings got set anyway.

Comment: I did a simple test on an OOB Team Site yesterday that disproved this assertion.  Web: Eastern Time, User A: Hawaii Time, User B: GMT.  Create an alert on the Calendar list for User A.  Enter a Calendar item with User B account.  Note that the Start/End date/time are based in GMT in the alert that should be in User A's inbox/spam folder, rather than EST or Hawaii.